# Monster dripping saliva

Tags: materials, physics, transparency

How can I make dripping saliva like this http://www.goodwp.com/images/201312/goodwp.com_30490.jpg I tried applying cloth physics to a plane, came out meh https://pasteboard.co/HAZwkw7.png . Maybe it's the material that doesn't make it look good (I used glass). Any help about material or modelling is appreciated.

Comment: Please show an image of your work to clarify and compare.  Is the goal a single still image or dynamic animation?  Cycles Render , Blender Render?

Comment: Fluid Simulation might be reasonable and difficult at very high resolution.  Composed and Beformed by various means.

Comment: Here's a pic https://pasteboard.co/HAZwkw7.png

Comment: For single still image as product you can consider 1 or more texture images  on a plane beformed by various means such as Surface Deform modifier.

Comment: Please place copies of  images in your question if possible, not external sources.  I will check back in 24 hours.